# What to do when there is Heteroscedasticity in a multiple regression model?

Tags: multiple-regression, heteroscedasticity

So I’m doing a multiple regression analysis with Y and 6 features. I realize that Heteroscedasticity exists between Y and 2 of the independent variables. How can I deal with this problem? Y is already normally distributed so using log transformation wouldn’t be optimal, besides Heteroscedasticity only happens with 2 of the independent variables not all of them. Is there a way to deal with this problem?

Language or software doesn’t matter

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What do you mean that there is heteroskedasticity for an independent variable? I would think of that as applying to the error terms (estimated by the residuals) not having constant variance.

Comment: Your question is unclear, can you clarify? Some plots? ... Then, there are many posta about heteroskedasticity on site [you could look through some of them](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heteroscedasticity?tab=Votes)